# Use GCC compiler in Termux?

Tags: termux

I don't like the default C compiler `clang` provided by Termux. Is there a way I can get GNU GCC in my Termux environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way to get gcc would be to add the community repo hosted by its-pointless at https://github.com/its-pointless/its-pointless.github.io. Sources are (more or less) available at https://github.com/its-pointless/gcc_termux.

Other popular packages available includes numpy and scipy.

More information about this and other community repositories can be found in the [termux wiki](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Package_Management#Community_Repositories).

To add this particular repository to your termux environment, run:

```
# Get some needed tools. coreutils for mkdir command, gnugp for the signing key, and apt-transport-https to actually connect to the repo
apt-get update
apt-get  --assume-yes upgrade 
apt-get  --assume-yes install coreutils gnupg2 apt-transport-https wget 
# Make the sources.list.d directory
mkdir $PREFIX/etc/apt/sources.list.d
# Write the needed source file - Added Missing "> character on line below
echo "deb [trusted=yes] https://its-pointless.github.io/files/ termux extras" > $PREFIX/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pointless.list
# Download signing key from https://its-pointless.github.io/pointless.gpg 
wget https://its-pointless.github.io/pointless.gpg
apt-key add pointless.gpg
# Update apt
apt update
```

(instructions taken from https://github.com/its-pointless/its-pointless.github.io/blob/master/setup-pointless-repo.sh)

Comment: Instructions have been updated, for anyone coming here better to check the sh file in the last link.

Comment: These repos don't have a gcc package.

Comment: `apt install gcc-10`

(or `gcc-9` or `gcc-8`)

Comment: @djao cannot finf gcc-10?

Comment: the instructions in the answer are outdated and invalid but everything works fine if you run https://its-pointless.github.io/setup-pointless-repo.sh first.

Comment: `which gcc-10`
`/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/gcc-10`
`$ gcc-10 --version`
`gcc-10 (GCC) 10.3.0`

Comment: Is there any command in termux to switch b/w compilers. Like changerover to gcc-10 from clang

Answer (score 4):

This is a very interesting solution.

First download [GCC for C4droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.n0n3m4.gcc4droid) from Google Play.

Go find its apk under `/data/app/com.n0n3m4.gcc4droid-#`, take the APK and extract `/assets/gcc.zip`. Now extract `gcc.zip` to

```
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/libexec
```

Apply `chmod -R 644` to the whole folder and `chmod -R 755` to `ARCH/bin`, `bin` and `libexec`. Link gcc programs to `$PREFIX/bin` and you'll be able to use GCC instead of Clang. Remember to add `-pie` when compiling executables.

Answer (score 1):

Install Arch Linux in Termux PRoot to get a full Linux development environment. 
See https://sdrausty.github.io/TermuxArch/docs/install for installation instructions.  Use `pacman -S base base-devel` to install the developer's environment which includes GCC.  [image: Arch Linux in Termux PRoot]

Answer (score 1):

I created termux repo with gcc 10.2.0, there how to install  https://cctools.info/index.php/Termux_repository_with_cctools_packages_(gcc_with_fortran_support_etc)

Add cctools packages public key:

```
wget -O - https://cctools.info/public.key | apt-key add -
```

Create a new repository list:

```
echo "deb https://cctools.info termux cctools" > $PREFIX/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cctools.list
```

Update packages lists:

```
apt update
```

Install the package gcc-cctools(it will install binutils-cctools automatically):

```
apt install gcc-cctools
```

Install the NDK package for your android architecture, use the latest one, for example for aarch64:

```
apt install ndk-sysroot-cctools-api-26-aarch64
```

To show all ndk sysroots for aarch64:

```
apt search ndk-sysroot-cctools | grep aarch64
```

Add directory with new compilers to PATH:

```
export PATH=$PREFIX/../cctools-toolchain/bin:$PATH
```

Check it:

```
gcc -v
```

Comment: You might want to add trusted if apt complains
https://askubuntu.com/a/1050824/1068697